# resizing an svg icon to the size of text in a nav menu

Tags: css, svg, icons, size

In a site Ia am developing from scratch, I have a `ul` & `li` nav menu like this one:

```
|*|Lorem Ipsum|Dolor Sit|Amet|
```

The `*` is an svg home icon directly embedded to the html page. This is the css I used to generate it:

```
#main_menu { /*id for ul*/
  overflow: auto;
}

#main_menu li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 1px;
  padding: 0px 4px;
  height: 16pt;
}

/* id for svg home icon in #main_menu */
#home_icon {
  fill: #eeeeee;
  stroke: #eeeeee;
}
```

I want to resize the svg icon according to the size of the other entries, however I do not know the size of the text. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `em` units?

```
#home_icon {
  fill: #eeeeee;
  stroke: #eeeeee;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}
```

Comment: It has resized but it still is not correctly aligned, and a scrollbar appears on the nav menu. I tried also with `vertical-align: middle;` but without luck.

Comment: We can't help more without seeing your actual code. Post a [MCVE].